# Dynamic refresh rate for 120Hz displays to save battery life?

Tags: x11, power-management, radeon

I moved to a laptop with integrated AMD Radeon 680M graphics and a 120Hz display currently running Kernel 6.1. In Windows 10 or later there's a feature called [Dynamic Refresh Rate](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-11-dynamic-refresh-rate/), which downgrades the display panel to 60Hz when there's no actual screen action to save battery life.

Is there a similar approach in Linux that can be enabled?

Comment: AFAIK it's not the case for Xorg/X11 - it always runs at the specified refresh rate unless instructed otherwise. I don't think running at 60Hz vs 120Hz could save you any meaningful amount of energy but you could try changing the refresh rate using `xrandr`. If you've got Wayland, I've no clue.